# How to untar zip file in linux/ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, command

I downloaded file which it's info.tar.gz located into directory called root.
so in the terminal linux/ubuntu I did this
cd ./root and did ls so I see the file called
info.tar.gz
so after Im in root directory I did
tar -zxvf info.tar.gz

but the file is still in the root directory zipped / tarred ..any help?
I tried to do cd ./root/info.tar.gz but it tells me that info.tar.gz isn't a directory

Any help please to untar/unzip the file in linux/ubuntu?

Comment: tar, unlike zip, does not remove original archive file.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) or at least the [tar(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) man page? Did you at least run the command `tar --help` in your terminal? For your next question, provide some [mre]. This question is off-topic here and better on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can just double click on the tar file and click 'extract' to unzip the file.

Another way to unzip the file via terminal :

Type the following command in the terminal after moved the directory where the zip file stored.

```
tar -xf info.tar.gz
```

Comment: I would recommend a verbose `tar xvf info.tar.gz` and check its contents before with `tar tvf info.tar.gz`